# Colobit LTD looks like Bitpetite! Anyone have any experience with them?

Tags: investing, fraud, lending

I signed up with Colobit.biz roughly a month ago. I have a coin base and BitConnect account along with a few others. Colobit was new and thought I'd be the first to sign up and get out before everyone else jumped in.

They are not allowing me to withdraw bitcoin!! Their customer service said it takes 7 days after I request. Funny how when you make a deposit its instant? It is starting to look like a typical ponzie. The site isn't written by someone fluent in English. Also, the 'stats' on the bottom keep increasing in every category except for total withdraws of Bitcoin.

1 week ago they boasted 500 BTC deposited and 51 BTC withdrawn. Now it's 2100 bitcoin deposited and 53 Btc withdrawn!! The money is flooding in. **Is ColoBit a Ponzie scheme??**

Comment: When you find yourself looking at a scheme that promises unrealistic gains, it is almost *always* a ponzi-scheme.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is ColoBit a Ponzie scheme?**

It's a scam of some sort, probably akin to a Ponzi scheme.

> **thought I'd be the first to sign up and get out before everyone else jumped in.**

Perhaps you knew what you were getting into.